# Are System V ABI and Itanium C++ ABI related?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compatibility, abi

I have basic understanding of what ABIs are While reading I found these statements

> System V ABI is used by most Unix-like systems in use today

and

> The GNU C++ compiler uses an industry-standard C++ ABI, the Itanium C++ ABI.

so now I am confused whether one is extension of other?

Suppose I have x86-64 machine with Linux and I compiled my C++ code on it. Now the resultant binary comply both these ABI?

Comment: itanium is for c++ and extends the c system v abi: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html

Comment: `I compiled my C++ code on it. Now the resultant binary comply both these ABI?` Now this completely absolutely depends on the compiler. You can use a compiler that does not "comply with the abi". Also, not the machine architecture is important, but the architecture you are compiling _for_. You can compile on ARM code _for_ x86-64 for Microsoft or Linux.